# Remove http:// or https:// and Trailing / in NetSuite Saved Search

Tags: formula, netsuite

Let me preface this by stating very clearly that I am not a developer and I'm new to NetSuite formulas.

I have a NetSuite saved search that include the Web Address (field id: {url})
I need to remove everything except the main part of the domain (end result should look like abc.com).

I have attempted to use REPLACE({url}, 'http://[,' ']) unsuccessfully.
I have also attempted various LTRIM, RTRIM, TRIM formulas without luck.
I found some information on using REGEXP_SUBSTR, but wasn't successful there either.

I was able to accomplish my goal in Excel using Excel string functions MID, LEN, and RIGHT, but that doesn't seem to translate in NetSuite.

I'd love some assistance.

Answer (score 0):

`REGEXP_SUBSTR({url}, '//(.)+')` --> get substring starting with //

`REPLACE({text}, '/')` --> replace / with nothing

The final formula is:
`REPLACE(REGEXP_SUBSTR({url}, '//(.)+'), '/')`

Answer (score 0):

Jala's answer doesn't seem to work for URLs such as https://stdun7.wixsite.com/stdunstansparish where it returns stdun7.wixsite.comstdunstansparish

In your saved search create a Forumula (Text) field with the following formula
REGEXP_REPLACE({url},'(^http[s]?://)([a-zA-Z0-9.-]*)(/?.*)', '\2')

I'll break down the arguments for the REGEXP_REPLACE function and how it all works...

- First argument - {url} the Field containing the url information to parse
- Second argument - regexp string
- Third argument =  replace regexp string

the regexp string has parentheses to denote capture groups of portions of the regular expression.

- The first capture group captures the protocol portion of the URL.
- The second capture group captures the next part, all permissible hostname characters until the end of the string, or until a '/'
- The third capture group captures the remaining portion of the string.

The replace string is used to prepare the return value of the REGEXP_SUBSTR function. Since the entire url is matched by the regexp, the entire string will be replaced by this expression, referencing the second capture group. (aka the hostname)

Since you say you're new to NetSuite formulas, I'll note that those functions are based on Oracle PL/SQL so if you want additional info or examples of how they work beyond what NetSuite provide, sometimes it's instructive to just google things like "pl/sql  REGEXP_SUBSTR" etc. to get additional documentation how how they work.

Another good resource is regex101.com, a helpful site to test regular expressions in advance....

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! I was able to accomplish my goal and I learned a TON!